# Apache Ignite and Infiniband

Tags: ignite, infiniband

I am using Apache Ignite on a cluster that has both 10G Ethernet and QDR Infiniband.  I would like to have Ignite use IP over Infiniband (IPoIB) to get the best network performance.  To that end, I have put the IP addresses for the IB connections in the Ignite configuration file.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"> 
   <property name="addresses">
      <list>
         <value>192.168.180.101:47500..47501</value>
         <value>192.168.180.102:47500..47501</value>
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

However when I run my Ignite client code and examine the node properties in Ignite visor, the first IP address listed is the Ethernet one. The IB address is listed next. How can I be sure that Ignite with use the IB address preferentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ignite binds to all available interfaces (`0.0.0.0`). To force a node to bind to a particular interface set `localHost` property in the configuration.

For example:

```
<property name="localHost" value="192.168.180.101">
```